# Getting Error on frontend after upgrading from Magento 2.1.9 to 2.2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, magento-upgrade

Getting Error after upgrading Magento 2.1.9 to 
Magento 2.2.2. It seems there is some issue in layout validation. Can't figure it out how exactly I should fix it?. 
Any help would be appreciated
[image]

Here is my theme/default.xml file:

```
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-dashboard-link-top" after="my-account-link" >
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Dashboard</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link-top" after="customer-account-navigation-dashboard-link-top" >
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">sales/order/history</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Past Orders</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="header.container">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="popup" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::popup/home_popup.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">sign-in</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link" template="account/link/authorization.phtml"/>

     <referenceBlock name="header.links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" destination="header.links" name="about"  before="top.links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">About Us</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">about_us</argument>
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">about-us</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" destination="header.links" name="help"  before="top.links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">How to Order</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">how-order</argument>
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">how-to-order</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" destination="header.links" name="contact-us"  before="top.links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Contact Us</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">contact-us</argument>
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">contact-us</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

        <!-- <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" destination="header.links" name="sign-in"  before="top.links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Sign In</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account/login</argument>
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">sign-in</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block> -->
        <move element="authorization-link" destination="header.links" before="top.links" />
        <move element="minicart" destination="header.links" after="top.links"/>


        <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" /> 
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="authorization-link-login" remove="true" /> 
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav.aside" template="html/topmenu-aside.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="header-wrapper" after="-">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="new.topsearch" template="Magento_Theme::html/form.new.phtml" before="logo"/>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" before="logo" name="new-sign-in"  >
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Sign In</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account/login</argument>
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">new-sign-in</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" before="logo" name="new-sign-in"  >
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Sign Out</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account/logout</argument>
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">new-sign-out</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
   </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you show me your default.xml file?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya: I have updated the default.xml file. please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your error log says, remove **destination** attribute from your blocks, i.e ( destination="header.links" ).

destination attribute is normally used with  where you define which element to move and where to move adding destination="".

remove destination from all blocks in your layout hope it will fix the issue.